# Time Series function or predict.gam function for predictions woth a fitter GAM Model?

Tags: regression, time-series, multivariate-analysis, simulation, mgcv

Experts,
I fitted a GAM Model with mgcv package containing a significant independent variable: number of days since first Action. Max.number of days were 40 days.
Dependant variable is Action of frogs.Question is Do you recommend gam.predict or time series function for predicting action patterns of frogs.Thanks a lot for your advice!!